# How to identify *.ko file given CONFIG_* name?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-module, kbuild

I enabled a couple new kernel modules as loadable (`m` as opposed to builtin with `y`) but do not understand how the CONFIG maps to the .ko file.

```
modprobe CONFIG_MY_CONFIG
insmod CONFIG_MY_CONFIG
modprobe MY_CONFIG
insmod MY_CONFIG
```

Comment: Totally arbitrary. Check *Makefile*:s for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to find usage of `CONFIG_<MYCONFIG>` variable in one of `Makefile`'s (except the top one). You may use `grep` utility for this (run from kernel source directory):

```
grep -r . --include Makefile -e "CONFIG_<MYCONFIG>"
```

Line with that usage normally looks like

```
obj-${CONFIG_<MYCONFIG>} += <driver>.o
```

Here `<driver>` is the name of the driver used by `modprobe`:

```
modprobe <driver>
```

For find exact path to the driver you may use `--show-depends` option for modprobe:

```
modprobe --show-depends <driver>
```

---

Makefile's used in Linux kernel are described in [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).